# How to call 2 different methods which return different String output in REST servcie

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

```
@Path("/hello")
    public class Hello {

     // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String getfirstname() {
        return "Hello Maclean";
      }

     // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String getlastname() {
        return "Hello Pinto";
      }
}
```

As seen in the above code there are 2 methods which return text response. if I try

```
localhost:8080/RestAPI/rest/hello
```

always the first method is called. I read a few documents and got to know that REST considers the resource per URL as unique. Is this Valid?. I know I can do this by sending query parameters to a single method and within the method sending different response according to query parameters. So can any one suggest a way where i can do this via url. No add on query parameters and all.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to add `@Path` to your methods, in addition to the `@Path` on the class, e.g.:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("firstname")
public String getfirstname() { ...

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("lastname")
public String getlastname() { ...
```

And they will be accessible as:

```
localhost:8080/RestAPI/rest/hello/firstname
localhost:8080/RestAPI/rest/hello/lastname
```

Answer (score 1):

well, this is true. REST dispatches requests by URL and HTTP Methods.

If you don't want to put query parameter for your case, you could use `@Path` on method.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

 // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Path("/firstname")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String getfirstname() {
    return "Hello Maclean";
  }

 // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
  @GET
  @Path("/lastname")
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public String getlastname() {
    return "Hello Pinto";
  }
}
```